# Is mandrill supporting “handlebar for dynamic content”?

Tags: mandrill

We are using a trial account for a short time, we are quite satisfied with the abilities of mandrill so far but we first need to make sure mandrill supports all our needs.

We have a major issue as below,

Mandrill documentation says mandrill is supporting “handlebar for dynamic content” but we see that it is not supported. So we want to understand if dynamic content is supported only for paid accounts or there is an issue with. ???

Comment: You can use Handlebars on the free trial account. If you're having issues with your implementation, it would probably help to check out the documentation (there are a ton of examples), test, then post your full code here with the desired outcome and what's not working as expected if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had it working in trial account before upgrading. 
Remember that you have to specify the merge language (the default is mailchip). 
You can set the merge language per message:
message.MergeLanguage = "handlebars"
or globally from Settings --> Sending Defaults --> Merge Language.